# D3 dynamically bold words in a Text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In my data I'm getting a string that can have 1 to 2 words ("one" or "one two"). If one word the font-weight needs to be 700, if two words, the first word needs to have 400 and second word 700. My approach has been to append the text separately which works for the most part but it's been challenging to make sure they always sit at the exact same location next to each other. Is there a better way to do this on a text path?

```js
function drawArcLabels(svg, arcs, groupId) {

 const text = svg
    .selectAll(".donutText")
    .data(arcs)
    .enter()

    text
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", d => {
      const classes = `${groupId}Text color-${d.data.name}`;
      return classes;
    })
    // Move the labels below the arcs for those slices with an end angle greater than 90 degrees
    .attr("dy", (d, i) =>
      d.startAngle > 4.4 ? 17 : d.endAngle > (90 * Math.PI) / 180 ? -8 : 17
    )
    .append("textPath")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("startOffset", function(d) {
      const secondWord = d.data.name.split(' ')[1]
      const firstWord = d.data.name.split(' ')[0]
      if (secondWord) {
        return `${50 - (firstWord.length) / 0.47}%`
      }
      return '50%'
    })
    .attr("fill", "#fff")
    .attr("href", (d, i) => `#${groupId + i}`)
    .text(d => d.data.name.toUpperCase().split(' ')[0])
    .attr("font-size", 11)
    .attr("font-weight", function(d) {
      return d.data.name.split(' ')[1] ? 400 : 900
    })

    text
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", d => {
      const classes = `${groupId}Text color-${d.data.name}`;
      return classes;
    })
    // Move the labels below the arcs for those slices with an end angle greater than 90 degrees
    .attr("dy", (d, i) =>
      d.startAngle > 4.4 ? 17 : d.endAngle > (90 * Math.PI) / 180 ? -8 : 17
    )
    .append("textPath")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("startOffset", function(d) {
      const firstWord = d.data.name.split(' ')[0]
      const secondWord = d.data.name.split(' ')[1]
      if (secondWord) {
        return '60%'
        //return (50 + (Math.floor((secondWord.length / 2) * 3))) + "%"
      }
    })
    .attr("fill", "#fff")
    .attr("href", (d, i) => `#${groupId + i}`)
    .text(d => d.data.name.toUpperCase().split(' ')[1])
    .attr("font-size", 11)
    .attr("font-weight", 900);
}
```

Comment: Use <tspan> elements and style them as you wish.

Comment: makes sense, could I just append it to the first text chain or would I have add it separately? My current solution works but makes it difficult to keep proper spacing between the two text elements along the textPath.

Comment: Whatever makes sense. It's hard to comment further as you've not provided code I can run.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the suggestion, I've figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RobertLongson for suggesting to use a tspan. My solution was to simply append the tspan at the end and treat it like a text string.

```js
function drawArcLabels(svg, arcs, groupId) {

 const text = svg
    .selectAll(".donutText")
    .data(arcs)
    .enter()

    text
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", d => {
      const classes = `${groupId}Text color-${d.data.name}`;
      return classes;
    })
    // Move the labels below the arcs for those slices with an end angle greater than 90 degrees
    .attr("dy", (d, i) =>
      d.startAngle > 4.4 ? 17 : d.endAngle > (90 * Math.PI) / 180 ? -8 : 17
    )
    .append("textPath")
    .style("text-anchor", 'middle')
    .attr("startOffset", '50%')
    .attr("fill", "#fff")
    .attr("href", (d, i) => `#${groupId + i}`)
    .text(d => d.data.name.toUpperCase().split(' ')[0])
    .attr("font-size", 11)
    .attr("font-weight", function(d) {
      return d.data.name.split(' ')[1] ? 400 : 900
    })
    .append('tspan')
    .text(d =>{ 
      const secondWord = d.data.name.toUpperCase().split(' ')[1]
      return secondWord ? ` ${secondWord}` : ''
})
```